# Why does this call to DOMDocument fail?

Tags: php, xml, ajax

In this PHP script I get information from an XML file to create elements on an HTML page. If I read the XML file with SimpleXMLElement then I am able to get the information.  I want to switch to use xpath to make it easier to get information from nested nodes.  But strangely enough the call to create a DOMDocument fails. This `$dom = new DOMDocument();` exits out of the PHP script without returning any errors to tell me why this happens.

The php script is called through ajax from javascript within the page.

Here is the PHP script.

```
<?php

function get_nodes() {
// load SimpleXML
/* $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true); */

$dom = new DOMDocument();  // The script fails here
$dom->load('communities.xml');

$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

// get document element  

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY"); 

$nnodes = sizeof($nodes);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Got ".$nnodes." nodes'); </script>";

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{

        echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'comdiv ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."px; left: ".$node->LEFT."px; 

width: ".$node->WIDTH."px; height: ".$node->HEIGHT."px;'> \n";

        /* echo "<script> alert ('<div id = \'".$node['ID']."\' class= \'comdiv ui-widget-content\' style = \'top: ".$node->TOP."; left: 

".$node->LEFT."; width: ".$node->WIDTH."; height: ".$node->HEIGHT.";\'>') </script>";*/

        echo "   <p class = 'comhdr editableText ui-widget-header'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"delete_div('".$node['ID']."');\">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"add_url('".$node['ID']."');\">Add URL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

        echo "</div> \n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable('option', 'handle', '.comhdr');\n";
        echo "</script>\n";


        $nodeid = $node['ID'];

        /* $xurls = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']/URLS/URL");

        foreach($xurls as $xurl) {

           echo "a url";

        }*/

}
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('.editableText').editableText();\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

   return;
}

echo get_nodes();

?>
```

Here is the place on the page where the script is called.

```
<body>

<div id="editdiv" class="comdiv ui-widget-content" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 850px; width:350px; height:250px; border:1px solid grey;">
    <p id="heading" class="comhdr editableText ui-widget-header">Editable</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
               //define php info and make ajax call to recreate divs from XML data
               $.ajax({
                   url: "get_nodes.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: { },
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (response) {

                       if (response != '') 
                       {
                          $(document.body).append(response);

                       }
                   }
               });
 });

</script>

</body>
```

There are other ajax calls where I am able to load the xml file with DOMDocument.  The only difference is that this ajax call is from the body of the page.

Comment: Turn on PHP errors (display_errors, error_reporting, error_level, error_log, etc...) and see what pops up. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php for a list of the options and settings.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and post the results.

Comment: @Marc-B @Tuga. Here is the error. `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\community\get_nodes.php on line 38`.  I don't know what makes PHP think that I am using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've got the error message posted, it's this series of code:

```
    echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
```

It'd have to be `$node->getAttribute('ID')`.

Comment: I thought this was only necessary if I wasn't using xpath.

Comment: a node retrieved via xpath is no different than a node retrieved via getElementById or by getElementByTagNames - it's just a dom node, and has to be used as such - it's not an array.

Comment: OK. When I changed the code to getAttribute and getElementsByTagNames it worked.  This wasn't a problem when I loaded the nodes with SimpleXMLElement.  Getting the node info was easier.  I could do `$node->TOP` instead of `$nodes->getElementsByTagNames('TOP')->item(0)->nodeValue`.  Instead of using the DOM with xpath.  I should have asked a question about how to access a specific node with an XML loaded with SimpleXMLElement.  I will make this a new question.

Comment: SimpleXML is just that. a highly simplified interface, and it's also a completely different object internally. Something that works in one doesn't mean anything at all as to how it'll work in the other. Apples and Oranges, even if both do happen to be Fruit.